# Image quality Problem Exporting from POWER BI to PPPT and then from PPT to PDF

Tags: powerbi

I am experiencing problem with Image quality while Exporting my Power BI Report to PPT latest version and then from PPT to PDF.

When I export from Power BI to PPT images and visuals looks fine, but when I convert PPt to PDF visuals are not clear and little bit blur.

Tried out many fixes regarding images size or PPT Designs but all in vain.

Any support and guide will be welcome.

Thank you

I tried many fix but couldn't get any desired result.